# How to show Elementor switch mode button on Specific pages templates in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, elementor

**how can i show Elementor switch mode button on specific pages templates only, not by default all pages in wordpress**

[image]

**i search a lot on internet but not found any good answer so i thought here i can get my answer**